# Matthew 10:22, to whom does "he" refer in the verse?

Tags: matthew

Matthew 10:22 (DRB):

> And you shall be hated by all men for my name's sake: but **he** that shall persevere unto the end, he shall be saved.

Matthew 10:22 (KJV):

> 22. And ye shall be hated of all {cf15I men} for my name's sake: but **he** that endureth to the end shall be saved.

To whom does "he" in the verse refer?, The apostles or the men preached by the apostles?

Comment: Note that this is a feature of English grammar and is not ambiguous in the Greek: "he" is whatever person "that [does something]". If you want a more detailed explanation of how this grammar works, you might consider asking on English Language & Usage.

Comment: It refers to anyone. Anyone at all. Anyone (and everyone) who endures to the end shall be saved. God is no respecter of persons. Anyone at all. And everyone who does so.

Comment: What does the "cf15l" mean?

Comment: @MCMastery it seems to be a term for a manuscript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Matt 10:22 has a very Koine Greek construction that uses a stand alone article (ὁ = ho) as an indefinite pronoun.  Thus, a better translation is given by several modern versions such as:

- NIV: You will be hated by everyone because of me, but **the one** who stands firm to the end will be saved.
- ESV: and you will be hated by all for my name’s sake. But **the one** who endures to the end will be saved.
- BSB: You will be hated by everyone because of My name, but **the one** who perseveres to the end will be saved.
- NASB: You will be hated by all because of My name, but it is **the one** who has endured to the end who will be saved.

Thus, the "he" in KJV & DRB is "the one who endures to the end".  This correctly give the gender as indefinite.

Ellicott comments:

> He that endureth to the end—i.e., endures, as the context shows, in
>   the confession of the name of Christ as long as the trial lasts, or to
>   the end of his own life. Such a one should receive “salvation” in its
>   highest sense, the full participation in the blessedness of the
>   kingdom of the Christ.

Barnes makes a similar comment:

> But he that endureth to the end ... - That is, to the end of life, be
>   it longer or shorter. He that bears all these unspeakable sufferings,
>   and who does not shrink and apostatize, will give decisive evidence of
>   attachment to me, and shall enter into heaven.

Comment: to whom  does "he" refer in the verse?, The apostles or men preached by the apostles?

Comment: @saiah, "he" refers to anyone who endures to the end. That includes the Apostles, people in the crowd to whom Jesus spoke, and everyone who hears these words.

Comment: Agreed - that is true

Comment: @Dottard to whom does **the one** refer?, The speech is clearly directed to the 12 apostles.

Comment: That is obviously correct but Jesus is discussing anyone who endures to the end which is (hopefully) all those who accept Jesus.

Answer (score 2):

The Christian disciple of Jesus in every age.

"You" here seems indeed to be directed to those in His direct hearing, but He seems to intend to include not only Christians persecuted in that first generation, but all Christians.

Consider Matthew 24 for example:

> Matthew 24:3-13 (DRB) And when he was sitting on mount Olivet, the disciples came to him privately, saying: Tell us when shall these things be? and what shall be the sign of **thy coming, and of the consummation of the world**? 4 And Jesus answering, said to them: Take heed that no man seduce you: 5 For many will come in my name saying, I am Christ: and they will seduce many. 6 And you shall hear of wars and rumours of wars. See that ye be not troubled. For these things must come to pass, but the end is not yet. 7 For nation shall rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom; and there shall be pestilences, and famines, and earthquakes in places: 8 Now all these are the beginnings of sorrows.
>
> 9 Then shall they deliver **you** up to be afflicted, and shall put **you** to death: and you shall be hated by all nations for my name's sake. 10 And then shall many be scandalized: and shall betray one another: and shall hate one another. 11 And many false prophets shall rise, and shall seduce many. 12 **And because iniquity hath abounded, the charity of many shall grow cold. 13 But he that shall persevere to the end, he shall be saved.** 14 And this gospel of the kingdom, shall be preached in the whole world, for a testimony to all nations, and then shall the consummation come.

Comment: to whom does "he" refer in the verse?, The apostles or men preached by the apostles?

Comment: The Greek article followed by a participle always means, "Whoever...," or "the one who..." That is, in this passage, "The Christian disciple of Jesus in every age."

Comment: could you include (the Christian disciples of Jesus in every age) in your post. Could you also say explicitly that the apostles not meant by the verse.

Comment: You: "could you include (the Christian disciples of Jesus in every age) in your post" The beginning of my unedited answer: "The Christian disciple of Jesus in every age."

Comment: could you say explicitly that the 12 apostles included or meant definitely.

Comment: I can't because I conclude they were not meant exclusively, but primarily.

Comment: logically, "he" in the verse means definitely the 12 apostles. How does the 12 apostles be saved if they persevered in preaching to the end?

Comment: Greek is a language, just as English or Arabic. If in Arabic Jesus said, "the one who is saved - hu is being saved." You would understand him to be saying, "whoever is saved..."